# Surface mount transformerless 230v to 3.3v on a small board

Tags: mains, 3.3v, transformerless

I am trying to design a 3.3V mains power supply to go on a PCB approximately 50x25mm in size (this will include other functions too!). I've come across the Supertex SR086, which is almost perfect, except that it can only pump out 60mA, which is likely to be too little for my application (Atmel AVR, Nordic NRF24L01+, triac, MOSFET, zero crossing detection, possibility of powering an LCD from it). I would appreciate any suggestions or case studies for similar solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the somewhat similar requirements the developers of the Belkin WEMO faced- tight quarters, reasonably high current low voltage supply required, mains input, WiFi communication, and an LED for an HMI.

[Here](http://cladlab.com/electronics/teardowns/belkin-wemo-teardown#gallery/4a26a356723a13130b7e12faacc31b30/1412/0) (Edit: Moved to [here](http://www.mbedded.ninja/electronics/teardowns/belkin-wemo-teardown)) is a teardown of that unit. You can see that the designers opted for a small switchmode power supply (and power output stage) on a separate board (probably two layer) from the high-density digital circuitry (probably multilayer).

That yellow mylar tape-wapped device on the left is a small switchmode power supply (flyback, almost surely) transformer. Aside from being able to deliver the required current, providing safety-agency acceptable galvanic isolation at that point means that they can use inexpensive switches, and don't need to worry about electrocuting someone through a switch operator (or LCD in your case). Judging from the small size, I'd guess they're using triple insulated wire rather than attempting to meet safety requirements by using tape.

Note also the extra insulation on the wires between the boards, for safety again.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Supertex part also has a minimum recommended output voltage of 9V.  You will find it very difficult if not impossible to get more than 60mA of well regulated 3.3V without a transformer.  You will also not have galvanic isolation which can be a huge safety concern.

The Supertex part acts similarly to a lamp dimmer, turning on during only part of the AC cycle.  Even with a large output cap they have about 2V of ripple on the output at 100mA.  So this approach isn't really viable at 3.3V out.

A straight non-isolated buck converter is out because the duty cycle would be too small.

A capacitive divider with post-regulation could maybe work, but the caps would be bigger than any transformer.

The transformer is probably a really good idea for safety and performance.

Comment: The VReg output on the SR086 provides 3.3V @ 60mA, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot about the linear regulator.  You could add a larger external linear regulator on the main output to get more current, but you'll still need the large output caps, and you'll burn a lot of power in the regulator (even the internal one at 60mA burns more than 1/3W).

Comment: Also, if you do go un-isolated do all your testing with an AC isolation transformer powering your circuit. Otherwise you'll be unable to hook a scope probe ground to your circuit and you will have a significant safety risk.  Best choice would be to use a transformer to get the lower voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use a transformerless power supply, if you can live without isolation. Of course, this is only a possibility if this whole circuit is isolated from the external world properly.

If you really want a transformerless power supply, you should check out Power Integration's integrated PWM controllers. There are nice buck converter [design examples](https://ac-dc.power.com/design-support/reference-designs/design-examples/) based on a single IC controller and some inductor, like these ones: [DI-139](https://ac-dc.power.com/design-support/reference-designs/design-examples/di-139-high-efficiency-dual-output-buck/) [DER-45](https://ac-dc.power.com/design-support/reference-designs/design-examples/der-45-18w-non-isolated-power-supply/)

Comment: Thanks Laszlo. You'll have to go quite out of your way to interact with the circuit in any way, there is no physical interaction with the board whatsoever.

Comment: Well, you mentioned some LCD display. That has to be isolated from the user.

Comment: The intention is to have the LCD behind transparent plastic at a later date.

Comment: A buck converter would also be very difficult.  At a rectified line voltage of say 170V the duty cycle to get to 3.3V would be about 2%.  That will lead to very short on times and difficulty with many control schemes.  It just gets worse at high line.

Comment: links seems broken

Comment: @kimstik I've updated the links.

Answer (score 1):

Laszlo mentioned the non-isolated offerings from Power Integrations and I'm going to mention the isolated type that includes a whole range of transformers from Premier Magnetics. here is one offering that is a 5V dc output but there are others that can be made to have a 3V3 output: -

[image]

There is also the slightly lower power linkswitch version with transformer: -

[image]

Again, premier make the transformer and PI make the chip.